# Dr Memory and the mysterious uninitialized read

Tags: c++, dr-memory

The code below doesn't do anything interesting, but the mystery is why would Dr Memory think there's an unitialized read? Any ideas?

```
#include <memory>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    int aa[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    std::unique_ptr<int[]> p {new int[10]};

    for (auto i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        p[i] = aa[i];
    }

    return 0;
} // <-- Dr Memory says UNINITIALIZED READ here
```

EDIT: Here's the full error details.

```
Error #1: UNINITIALIZED READ: reading 0x0028ff20-0x0028ff24 4 byte(s)
# 0 __mingw_glob                              [src/main.cpp:14]
# 1 _setargv                                  [src/main.cpp:14]
# 2 __mingw_CRTStartup
# 3 mainCRTStartup
# 4 ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain    +0x62     (0x772c8fe2 <ntdll.dll+0x38fe2>)
# 5 ntdll.dll!RtlInitializeExceptionChain    +0x35     (0x772c8fb5 <ntdll.dll+0x38fb5>)
Note: @0:00:00.297 in thread 9780
Note: instruction: cmp    (%esi) $0x0040a11e
```

Comment: Does this "Dr Memory" really tell you nothing other than the location? Nothing about the block, offset, stack or executing line of code at the time the read's attempted etc...?  If not, you might want to check out its competition....

Comment: I edited my question to add the details it provides.

Comment: you need to provide the correct deleter. The code will try to `delete` the data, but it should `delete []` it.

Comment: It might be that the problem is in the mingw or ntdll code and nothing to do with your program... have you checked whether a program that simple returns, or say - creates a `std::string` and calls `size()` on it - reports the same error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line indicated in your `main` function is not the line where the error occurred. The error occurred in `__mingw_glob` as indicated by the stack trace, and this is occurring *before* any of your code is called. (This is the function which expands filename wildcards passed on the command line. On Linux this job is done by the shell, but on Windows it is the responsibility of the C Runtime.)

In other words it is occurring in the `mingw` library. It's likely that this is harmless false positive and you should simply add an exclusion.

I suggest that probably Dr Memory has wrongly identified this as uninitialized since it was initialised by the operating system before any of your code ran, or by code which ran before DrMemory was initialised, or because it was passed to a system call which does not in fact read the memory but only writes to it.

Why is it showing the wrong line in your function?

Debuggers try to show you relevant information by default. Since it is generally much more likely that your code is buggy rather than library code, the debugger will show the most recent instance of your code on the call stack. For example, if an error occurs in the implementation-specific depths of a call to `free` it is unlikely to be the library heap code which is at fault, so instead your code which called `free` would be identified as the likely culprit.

In your case there is none of your code on the call stack, so the algorithm is failing to locate any and is showing you an erroneous location.